# prime number function not printing output

Tags: python

I made a function that checks if the number is a prime, but when I call it, I don't get any screen output:

```
def is_prime(x):
    x = int(x)
    if x < 0 or x == 1:
        return False
        print('no')
    else:
        temp_div = 10
        while temp_div > 1:
            if x % temp_div == 0:
                return False
                print('no')
                break
            else:
                temp_div -= 1
        if temp_div == 1:
            return True
            print('yes')
        else:
            return False
            print('no')
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call "return", the function immediately ends. Move all your print statements immediately before the "return" statements.

Alternatively, rearrange your code so that the prime-checking function contains no print statements. Instead, have another piece of code that uses it, and prints  out "yes" or "no" depending on the output. This helps you keep the calculation code and the display code nicely clean and separate from each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return False
    print('no')
```

swap `return` and `print` lines similar to these ones:

```
    print('no')
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think you don't need a "break" statement after return. "return" will stop your function execution, not executing your "break" statement.